# How to set cargo drones back to Trading?

Tags: x4-foundations

I've captured some Barbarossas. On newly captured ships the cargo drones are set to `Trading`:

[image: Trading cargo drones]

But if I change them to `Collect All` they can't be changed back to `Trading`:

[image: Cargo drone can't be set to Trading]

What do I need to do to set cargo drones to `Trading`?